# Angular2 JSONP Callback not working

Tags: angular, jsonp

I'm working with Angular2 CLI App hosted on Firebase and uses Firebase Realtime DB. In order to authenticate the user of the app through a third-party OAuth and to provide for a secure custom token to be generated, I'm using the Google Cloud function to handle the OAuth and create the token. This token is then returned to the Angular2 cli app through a JSONP request from the CLI app to the Cloud function. The reason for using JSONP is that the cloud functions are hosted on a google domain which creates the CORS issue.

I have worked out the complex back and forth of OAuth and issuing the final JSONP request successfully as follows -

```
      let tokenFunctionURL = 'https://us-central1-' + [FIREBASE PROJECT ID] + '.cloudfunctions.net/token';
  let url = tokenFunctionURL +
    '?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK';

jsonp
    .request(url, {method:'Get'})
    .map(res=>res.json())
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
```

In response to the above GET call I do receive, what I believe is a valid response as follows -

```
/**/ typeof __ng_jsonp____req0_finished === 'function' && __ng_jsonp____req0_finished({"token":"eyJhbGci..."});
```

But along with that I get the following error message in Chrome developer console -

```
error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Response with status: 200 Ok for URL: https://us-central1-[FIREBASE PROJECT ID}.cloudfunctions.net/token?callback=__ng_jsonp____req0_finished
Subscriber.js:227 Uncaught Response {_body: "JSONP injected script did not invoke callback.", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "Ok", headers: Headers…}
```

I've been trying the figure this out for many hours now but just don't know how to get past it. I did see other threads in Stack Overflow that address this issue but there seems no clear answer, or at least, one that works for me.

Tracking down the code in Angular, I found the following link - [I found this link](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bebedfed24d6fbfa492e97f071e1d1b41e411280/packages/http/src/backends/jsonp_backend.ts), which seems to indicate that the JSONP call didn't finish (or the method finish() was never called by the internals of Angular 2 stack).

Thanks.

EDIT - I solved this issue by upgrading the Angular2 stack from 2.4.6 to 2.4.10. Apparently the issue was introduced in that specific release. See here - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14267
Though the question was down voted for apparently valid reasons, I hope this discovery will help someone who's facing the same issue.